# How to add Transport or websockets as "AmqpWebSockets" in azure service bus client in nestJS?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, azureservicebus

I have azure service bus and I am creating ServiceBusClient. 
But I want to set Transport type as AmqpWebSockets.

```
const serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
                //options?: ServiceBusClientOptions
            const receiver = serviceBusClient.createReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName)

            const msgs = await receiver.getMessageIterator();
            const myMessageHandler = async (message) => {
     
                this.cacheManager.reset();
                console.log(`message.body: ${message.body}`);
            };
            const myErrorHandler = async (args) => {
                console.log(
                    `Error occurred with ${args.entityPath} within ${args.fullyQualifiedNamespace}: `,
                    args.error
                );
            };


             receiver.subscribe({
                processMessage: myMessageHandler,
                processError: myErrorHandler
            });

            await delay(15000);
            await receiver.close();
            await serviceBusClient.close();
```

I have one option in ServiceBusClientOptions Optional parameter to set webSockets but I am not able to add this AmqpWebSockets.  
Can you please help me how to and where to add this?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/typescript/src/useProxy.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AmqpWebSockets mode with Azure service bus, you can implement it with `ServiceBusClientOptions` in package `@azure/service-bus`. `ServiceBusClientOptions` has a `webSocketOptions` constructor argument. `webSocketOptions` is a option to configure the channelling of the AMQP connection over Web Sockets. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview#amqp-10-and-service-bus)

[image]

[image]

For example

```
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const HttpsProxyAgent = require("https-proxy-agent");

const proxyInfo =

const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyInfo);

  const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, {
    webSocketOptions: {
      // No need to pass the `WebSocket` from "ws" package if you're in the browser
      // in which case the `window.WebSocket` is used by the library.
      webSocket: WebSocket,
      webSocketConstructorOptions: { agent: proxyAgent }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code snippet. Just one more thing, if I want to pass AmqpWebSockets, what should be there in { agent: proxyAgent} ?

Comment: @DhruvinMashruwala The package uses Amqp to connect service bus, you need to provide websocket connection.